# Why the current decreases with increase in voltage while according to Ohm's law current is directly proportional to the voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Could you explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the Ohm's law violated here?

No, the Ohm's law is not violated since Ohm's law relates the voltage *across* ('between the ends') of a conductor to the current *through* the conductor.

But the voltage *on* a transmission line (the voltage referenced to ground) is *not* the voltage *across* the transmission line (the voltage difference between the ends of the transmission line).

To apply Ohm's law correctly requires understanding *which* voltage and current are related by it.

As given in another answer, for a given power, we require that the product of the transmission line voltage and current is constant.   So, holding the power constant, an increase in voltage results in a decrease in current.

Since the [ohmic losses in a transmission line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating#Reason_for_high-voltage_transmission_of_electricity) are proportional the square of the current, reducing the current by 50% cuts the power loss by 75%.

Answer (score 1):

The current required to carry a **given power** decrease when you increase the voltage because the power is the product of the current with the voltage (and power factor).

Answer (score -3):

as per the formul;I=P/V......SO if we keep the value of 'P' CONSTANT AND VARRY THE VALUE OF 'V'then we get the value of i will less.on the other hand ohms law applicable only in a particular conductor's two end......and should have fix impedance.In transmission line we are using transformer and it doesn't have fixed impedance becoz we always doing stepup and step down to the power.