# How high voltage and low current is beneficial for power transmission which is contradicting $V²/R$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, power

I have read that during power transmission high voltage is used because for same power output, high voltage produce low current and due to low current, according to I²R, heat loss through cables are reduced.

But my question arises that if high voltage is used then according to V²/R, heat loss will still be high.

I cannot understand the heat loss change by the two formulas I²R and V²/R although both are formulas of same thing (Power/Heat Loss)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the current decreases with increase in voltage in transmission lines? But according to Ohm's law current should increase with Voltage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142001/)

Comment: Not really, the question you suggested is about a confusion about Ohm (where the questioner didn't account for resistance being constant) but my question is about the confusion created by the formula of Heat Loss (I²R and V²R). Power transmission isn't the main issue here :)

Comment: You have the same confusion. The V that would determine the transmission loss and would be used in the $V^2/R$ formula is the V between the ends of the transmission wire, not the V between the transmission wire and ground.

Comment: Do you mean V remains constant or something when current is less??

Comment: V (the voltage between the ends of the wire) falls if the current is less (assuming you use the same wire diameter) since V = IR.

Comment: Another related question: [How power lines use high voltages with a low current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195809/22927) (I link directly to the relevant answer)

Comment: @ADITYADAS, every electrical object that current passes through produces a voltage drop.  The transmission line that carries current to your house (and those electrical objects) also introduces a voltage drop on the transmitted current, which is unmetered and lost power for the transmission company.  The way to minimize that loss is to transmit the minimum required current, which necessarily requires transmitting that power at the maximum practical voltage.  That transmission voltage is NOT the voltage drop across the transmission line.

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is the current passing by any length of the wires of the transmission line, and $R$ is the resistance of that length. So $I^2R$ is the power dissipated there.

In order to compare the same stuff, $V$ is the voltage between the endpoints of some length of the wires.

As $V = RI, \frac{V^2}{R} = I^2R$

When we say $220 V$ or $30kV$, it is not between some meters of the same wire, but includes the loads. Most of the power is dissipated there, where it should be, instead of in the transmission lines.

Answer (score 1):

A simple electrical power transmission system is a series circuit ABCD. A and D are the terminals of the generator. B and C are the terminals of the *load*, which we are supplying with energy. AB and CD are the transmission wires between generator and load. Please draw your own diagram, representing the load and the transmission wires  by resistances.

We can therefore distinguish 4 voltages related by:
$$V_{AD}=V_{AB}+V_{BC}+V_{CD}\ \ \ \text{in which}\ \ \ V_{AB}=V_{CD}.$$

In each transmission wire (resistance $R_{wire}$) we have

$$\text{Power dissipated}= I^2 R_{wire}=\left(\frac{V_{AB}}{R_{wire}}\right)^2 R_{wire}=\frac{V_{AB}^2}{R_{wire}}.$$
For a given $R_{wire}$, we can reduce this waste by making $I$ small, which implies a small $V_{AB}\ (=IR_{wire})$.

But the power supplied to the load is $IV_{BC}$. Therefore to supply a given power to the load, $V_{BC}$ must be large to compensate for the small $I$. Clearly (see first equation above) the generator voltage, $V_{AD}$, must be somewhat larger than $V_{BC}$.  [Note that the load must be 'tailored' to accept a low current at a high voltage; its effective resistance must be high. This constraint, and the technical difficulties that would be encountered in trying to make a high voltage generator, call for transformers and alternating voltages – but that's another story.]

Advice to take away: be careful to distinguish the different voltages in a series circuit!