# Heating Effect of Current wrt Transformers

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, electrical-resistance

I just learnt that we use step up transformers to reduce heating losses in overhead wires. I was given some values.

Say, the power plant is a 1 million watt rated plant.
The voltage is $400V$ at the plant, so the Current must be $2500A$.

$R = V/I$

R = 400/2500 = 0.16 ohms

Now, using a step up transformer, voltage is $33000 V$. Current must be $30.3 A$. New resistance is coming as $1090 ohms$

Q1) How has resistance changed when the length of the wire is the same and current decreased. $R = ρL/A$

Q2) Say heat produced $H = I^2Rt$, first case it is $2500^2 *.16 = 1,000,000J$ and with $V^2/R$ we also get 1 million J, but in second case, we also get 1 mil joules. $H = 33000^2/1090 = 1,000,000$ and $H = 30.3^2*1090 = 1,000,000 Joules$

something is wrong in my concepts or calculations, it might be a very dumb question, but i am not able to understand this stuff.

Thank you for any replies!!

Comment: se https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/776005/how-high-voltage-and-low-current-is-beneficial-for-power-transmission-which-is-c/776017#776017 and many other  similar questions/answers on this site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your initial reasoning, as follows.

When you calculate the resistance in the case of the generator source (400V, 2500A) the "resistance" you get is the *source impedance* of the generator itself and for the transmission line case it is the *lumped impedance of the transmission line*.

Your calculations require knowledge of the *load impedance* at the far end of the transmission line, not the *characteristic impedance* of either the generator or the transmission line.